# How can I make VS Code open with a blank text editor tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I'm trying to set up VS Code such that when the program is just opened (not via the context menu  for a file or clicking on a file) a new blank text file is open and ready to start typing in - similar to when Notepad++ is opened - or most other text editors, for that matter.

Searching for "VS Code open with new file" and many variants only brings me to articles/posts about opening a new file in a new tab or window. That's not what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 41):

**File > Preferences > Settings**

Search for `startupEditor`

Change

`"workbench.startupEditor": "welcomePage"`

to

`"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile"`

or select `newUntitledFile` from dropdown

Comment: This still restore all the tab which I don't want,  Need to disable hotExit too

Answer (score 2):

In File > Preferences > Settings there is the following option listed under the Window section:

// Controls how windows are being reopened after a restart. Select 'none' to always start with an empty workspace, 'one' to reopen the last window you worked on, 'folders' to reopen all windows that had folders opened or 'all' to reopen all windows of your last session.
"window.restoreWindows": "none",

Using the editor in the right pane you can add:
"window.restoreWindows": "none"

Which will open an empty workspace with a link that says "new file". It's not exactly the solution you're looking for but it's the closest one I'm aware of.

Comment: I didn't realize that section was there, but it doesn't quite do what I'm looking for. I found precisely what I was looking for, though.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
// Controls how windows are being reopened after starting for the first time. This setting has no effect when the application is already running.
// `none`: Never reopen a window. Unless a folder or workspace is opened (e.g. from the command line), an empty window will appear.
"window.restoreWindows": "none",

// Controls whether unsaved files are remembered between sessions, allowing the save prompt when exiting the editor to be skipped.
// `off`: Disable hot exit. A prompt will show when attempting to close a window with editors that have unsaved changes.
"files.hotExit": "off",

// Controls which editor is shown at startup, if none are restored from the previous session.
// `newUntitledFile`: Open a new untitled text file (only applies when opening an empty window).
"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
```

Answer (score 0):

This also stopped working for me.  But I created a shortcut on my Taskbar like the following, and it does what I was looking for:

"C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" C:\Users\myname\Downloads\Untitled